# Best way to transfer data between two views managed by a UITabViewController

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

What's the best way to get a reference to other views using default controllers? My MainView.xib is a TabBarController, and I want to know the best way to call methods from one view on another, or change data properties. Any transfer of data will also necessitate that the tabs switch, but I haven't figured out how to programatically control that yet, either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass UITabViewController.